# tooltip mouse tracking only works outside graphed data

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to implement the tooltip technique from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/e5daff57a04c2639125e) into an area chart.

The tooltip will only track the mouse when the cursor is above the area drawn by the graph, unlike in the example, where it will track the mouse as long as it's in the svg window.

I have not been able to figure out what I did wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

```js
var tdata = [

{
    "date":"2016-06-28 05:47:10",
    "value": 80
},
{
    "date":"2016-06-28 05:47:20",
    "value": 90
},
{
    "date":"2016-06-28 05:47:30",
    "value": 82
},
{
    "date":"2016-06-28 05:47:40",
    "value": 78
},
{
    "date":"2016-06-28 05:47:15",
    "value": 85
} ,

{
    "date":"2016-06-28 05:47:25",
    "value": 70
} ,

{
    "date":"2016-06-28 05:47:35",
    "value": 95
},

{
    "date":"2016-06-28 05:47:45",
    "value": 88
} , 

];
  
  // d3 code 

  var w = 800;
  var h = 300;

  var firstappend = false;

  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 90, left: 40},
      width = w - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("#disp").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("cardinal")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
      });

    var area = d3.svg.area()
      .interpolate("cardinal")
      .x(line.x())
      .y1(line.y())
      .y0(y(0));

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)  //xbar
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(d3.time.minutes, 4)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%m/%d %M')); 

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient('left')
        .tickPadding(8);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(+"+0+"," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-8px")
        .attr("dy", "-4px")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

    svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis').attr("transform", "translate(-"+0+"," +0 + ")")
      .call(yAxis);

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

    var lines = svg.selectAll('.property');

    var lE;


/////////////////////////tooltip code:

var focus = svg.append("g") 
    .style("display", "none");

var  bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;
      
    focus.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "y")
        .style("fill", "red")
        .style("stroke", "black")
       // .style('opacity', '0.5')
        .attr("r", 5);
    
   var wind = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("pointer-events", "all")
        .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); });
      //  .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); });
        
/////////////////////////////////

function update(dataset){
// parse new date strings
 dataset.forEach(function(d) { 
  if(typeof(d.date) === "string"){ d.date = parseDate(d.date); }
});
// sort by date
dataset = dataset.sort(sortByDateAscending);
// update domain
x.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function (d) { return d.date; }));

svg.selectAll("g.y.axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.selectAll("g.x.axis")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-8px")
  .attr("dy", "-4px")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

// do first append once
if(!firstappend){
  init(dataset); 
  firstappend = true;
}

// update new data
lE.select(".tarea").attr("d", function(d) { return area(dataset); });

/////////////////////////tooltip code:
 
wind.on("mousemove", mousemove);

function mousemove() {
          var tset = dataset;
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(tset, x0, 1),
        d0 = tset[i - 1],
        d1 = tset[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;

    focus.select("circle.y")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," +
                             y(d.value) + ")");
  }     
   
     
//////////////////////////////////

}

function init(dataset){

lines = svg.selectAll('.property')
      .data(dataset, function(d) {
        return d.property;
      });

lE = lines.enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'property');


      lE.append("path")
        .attr("class", "tarea")
        .style('fill', 'red')
        .style('opacity', '0.5')
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return area(dataset);
        });

}

  function sortByDateAscending(a, b) {
    return Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date);
};



update(tdata);
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="disp"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the area of the chart is blocking out the element which we are watching for mouseover...

Allowing pointer events to pass through .tarea will get around this.

CSS:

```
.tarea{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z24zy61w/

Comment: Thanks!, I didn't realize it could in the css.